# Inserting unicode symbol for rational numbers ℚ using TeX input method

Tags: latex, unicode, tex

Hello good people of Emacs!

To insert unicode math symbols I use **TeX input method**. This way I get unicode character `ℝ` by typing `\Bbb{R}`, `ℕ` by typing `\Bbb{N}`, `ℤ` by typing `\Bbb{Z}`, etc...

**I'm unable to get** symbol `ℚ`, since typing `\Bbb{Q}` does not insert unicode character.

Any Ideas what can be the source of this error?

Comment: If it helps the code point is `211A`, so it can be entered via `C-x 8 RET 211A`.  The TeX input method covers N, P, R and Z, but not the Q nor C which are in the 10646 character set.  See http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/3104/2710 which may help with  how to extend the input method.

Comment: @AndrewSwann: Please consider posting your comment as an answer (which can be accepted, so the question is not left "unanswered").

Comment: @Drew OK done, but this is very close to being a duplicate.

Comment: If you set `read-quoted-char-radix` to 16 (its default value is 8), entering characters by hexadecimal value becomes a bit easier: `C-q 211a RET`.

Answer (score 7):

The character set used is in the ISO 10646 encoding, which includes the following double stroked letters

```
C H N P Q R Z
```

and no others.  Unfortunately the TeX input method only defines shortcuts for

```
N P R Z
```

as `describe-input-encoding` will tell you.  However, [How can I add characters to an input method?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/3104/2710) shows you how to add extra sequences to this input encoding.  Thus all you need to know is that double stroked Q is at code point 211A to add this character.  To find the code points for other characters have a look at the ISO 10646 standard at http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/index.html .

Comment: Hmm, I also find a double struck ℍ (for the quaternions), but alas, no double struck O for the octonions. However, there are also two double struck Greek letters: ℾℿ. I have no idea why these are considered so special. The quaternions really *are* useful, though. The octonions are a bit more marginal.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Yes, I missed H, thank you for pointing that out.  The double struck greek letters are indeed strange....

Comment: Please report the lack of C Q ... via `M-x report-emacs-bug`.