# How to type superscript Roman numeral in Emacs, e.g., by using TeX input method?

Tags: input-method, tex

One can type normal [Roman numerals](https://unicode-table.com/en/sets/roman-numerals/) by using `C-x 8 RET`. For example, to type `Ⅲ` one use `C-x 8 RET 2162 RET`. Furthermore, one can type superscript numbers, English letters and Greek ones by using the TeX input-method. For example, to type superscript alpha one switch to the TeX input-method and use `^\alpha`. However, it seems that one cannot type superscript Roman numerals, not even by [expanding the TeX input-method](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TeXInputMethod) [as suggested](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3104/how-can-i-add-characters-to-an-input-method) ?

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, you are asking for a way to insert a superscript Roman numerals as raw text.

Let's first find out whether such characters exist. Note that not all characters have a superscript or subscript form. For example, in the table "Latin superscript and subscript letters" at [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts) in Wikipedia, it is mentioned that there is no superscript minuscule character for the character "q".

We know some names of the superscript characters

- ²: SUPERSCRIPT TWO
- ⁹: SUPERSCRIPT NINE
- ᴬ: MODIFIER LETTER CAPITAL A
- ᶿ: MODIFIER LETTER SMALL THETA
- ᵅ: MODIFIER LETTER SMALL ALPHA

As we can see above, there is no common pattern for the characters which are considered superscripts. For this reason, if we were to search in the names of all characters, we would need to list all those characters which contain the string `ROMAN` in its name.

We can print all the available characters which contain `ROMAN` in its name by executing the following

```el
(require 'cl-lib)

(let ((chars (cl-loop for code from 0 to #x10FFFF
     for name = (get-char-code-property code 'name)
     when (and name (string-match "ROMAN" (get-char-code-property code 'name)))
     collect `(,(number-to-string code) ,(format "%c" code) ,name))))
  (dolist (char chars)
      (princ (format "%s\n" (mapconcat 'identity char " ")))))
```

```
8544 Ⅰ ROMAN NUMERAL ONE
8545 Ⅱ ROMAN NUMERAL TWO
8546 Ⅲ ROMAN NUMERAL THREE
8547 Ⅳ ROMAN NUMERAL FOUR
8548 Ⅴ ROMAN NUMERAL FIVE
8549 Ⅵ ROMAN NUMERAL SIX
8550 Ⅶ ROMAN NUMERAL SEVEN
8551 Ⅷ ROMAN NUMERAL EIGHT
8552 Ⅸ ROMAN NUMERAL NINE
8553 Ⅹ ROMAN NUMERAL TEN
8554 Ⅺ ROMAN NUMERAL ELEVEN
8555 Ⅻ ROMAN NUMERAL TWELVE
8556 Ⅼ ROMAN NUMERAL FIFTY
8557 Ⅽ ROMAN NUMERAL ONE HUNDRED
8558 Ⅾ ROMAN NUMERAL FIVE HUNDRED
8559 Ⅿ ROMAN NUMERAL ONE THOUSAND
8560 ⅰ SMALL ROMAN NUMERAL ONE
8561 ⅱ SMALL ROMAN NUMERAL TWO
8562 ⅲ SMALL ROMAN NUMERAL THREE
8563 ⅳ SMALL ROMAN NUMERAL FOUR
8564 ⅴ SMALL ROMAN NUMERAL FIVE
8565 ⅵ SMALL ROMAN NUMERAL SIX
8566 ⅶ SMALL ROMAN NUMERAL SEVEN
8567 ⅷ SMALL ROMAN NUMERAL EIGHT
8568 ⅸ SMALL ROMAN NUMERAL NINE
8569 ⅹ SMALL ROMAN NUMERAL TEN
8570 ⅺ SMALL ROMAN NUMERAL ELEVEN
8571 ⅻ SMALL ROMAN NUMERAL TWELVE
8572 ⅼ SMALL ROMAN NUMERAL FIFTY
8573 ⅽ SMALL ROMAN NUMERAL ONE HUNDRED
8574 ⅾ SMALL ROMAN NUMERAL FIVE HUNDRED
8575 ⅿ SMALL ROMAN NUMERAL ONE THOUSAND
8576 ↀ ROMAN NUMERAL ONE THOUSAND C D
8577 ↁ ROMAN NUMERAL FIVE THOUSAND
8578 ↂ ROMAN NUMERAL TEN THOUSAND
8579 Ↄ ROMAN NUMERAL REVERSED ONE HUNDRED
8581 ↅ ROMAN NUMERAL SIX LATE FORM
8582 ↆ ROMAN NUMERAL FIFTY EARLY FORM
8583 ↇ ROMAN NUMERAL FIFTY THOUSAND
8584 ↈ ROMAN NUMERAL ONE HUNDRED THOUSAND
65936  ROMAN SEXTANS SIGN
65937  ROMAN UNCIA SIGN
65938  ROMAN SEMUNCIA SIGN
65939  ROMAN SEXTULA SIGN
65940  ROMAN DIMIDIA SEXTULA SIGN
65941  ROMAN SILIQUA SIGN
65942  ROMAN DENARIUS SIGN
65943  ROMAN QUINARIUS SIGN
65944  ROMAN SESTERTIUS SIGN
65945  ROMAN DUPONDIUS SIGN
65946  ROMAN AS SIGN
65947  ROMAN CENTURIAL SIGN
113741  DUPLOYAN LETTER ROMANIAN I
113750  DUPLOYAN LETTER ROMANIAN U
```

As we could see above, there is no `SUPERSCRIPT` characters for the roman numerals. For this reason, inserting such characters as raw text (i.e. what you are requesting) is not possible.

PD: I tried searching `"superscript roman numeral"` (note the double quotes) in Google and found some websites ([here](https://css.libanswers.com/faq/215744), [here](https://internal.ncl.ac.uk/ask/numeracy-maths-statistics/core-mathematics/calculus/differentiation.html)) which encourage to use such characters for different purposes, so those characters might be commonly used in other contexts not yet of interest to the Unicode Consortium.